# Windows Explorer line above command bar

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, crash

I've just got a new laptop and am having problems with explorer.exe crashing. I noticed there is an extra line just above the command bar in Windows Explorer as shown below:

[image]

I was wondering if this is some kind of add-on added by the OEM?

why is this line there and how can i get rid of it?

UPDATE: I've found out where the bar came from, it was because the File, Edit...... bar was not locked, I locked it and it removed the line. Doesn't fix explorer crashing though :(

Comment: What brand of laptop is it?

Comment: It's an asus laptop

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/778412/get-rid-of-the-file-explorer-grey-bar-line

Comment: Voting to reopen, no idea why this was considered as "not a real question". The question is clearly stated "why is this line there and how can i get rid of it?".

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt No, the question is about why explorer crashes. The UPDATE by the OP shows that the extra line is irrelevant. The question should be edited to remove all references to that line (including the pic), which then leaves only the unanswerable "My explorer crashes".

Comment: @JanDoggen I see, good point, thanks for the catch, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of Asus' bloat-ware is buggy and unnecessary.  I've removed 95% of the Asus bloat-ware from my laptop.  Take a look at this article and see if there are some hints as to what could be the trouble: [Asus Utility and Bloatware Guide](http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus/380681-asus-utility-bloatware-guide.html)

A quick glance suggests the following programs may be an issue:

- Multi Frame
- Live Update

Answer (score 0):

That line is in place separating the Aero transparency from the buttons on the Window. It's a part of Windows Explorer and cannot be removed.

Comment: I don't have those extra gray pixels on any of my Windows 7 machines, even after changing the Aero colour.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food I can't reproduce the error in any way at any rate.

Comment: Update to question about the line, is due to File,Edit etc menu bar not being locked

Comment: @Chris I unlocked it and didn't get that..

Comment: @SimonSheehan oh thats odd, did you also have the menu bar hiding automatically?

Comment: @Chris nope I didn't