# Get rid of the file explorer grey bar line

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I have just received my Asus ROG G750 with Windows 8.1. On the file explorer I get a grey bar that seems resizable but that doesn't move and I don't know what it is.

Here is a screenshot of the file explorer with the grey bar:

[image]

here is a screenshot of how file explorer looks on other systems:
[image]

I don't know why I have it and honestly I'd really like to get rid of it.

Comment: I see nothing odd about that screenshot.

Comment: This is a screenshot on another system: http://i.imgur.com/jbX8kfg.png

Comment: Has the ribbon been disabled?

Comment: If you mean closed or reduced then yes, when the ribbon is showing the grey bar is still there: http://i.imgur.com/dHYitEc.png

Comment: http://www.askvg.com/fix-a-new-strange-line-appears-below-ribbon-toolbar-in-windows-8-and-8-1-explorer/

Comment: Thanks, I never though IE would help.

Comment: @magicandre1981 That looks like it helped the OP. You should add that as an answer with steps to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fix is to enable "Lock the toolbars" option](http://www.askvg.com/fix-a-new-strange-line-appears-below-ribbon-toolbar-in-windows-8-and-8-1-explorer/) and it'll remove the ugly line from Windows Explorer.

Open Internet Explorer and then right-click on titlebar or toolbar and enable "Lock the toolbars" option.

[image]

Comment: If you want to avoid opening IE for some reason, then in Windows Explorer hit "Alt" to show the menu bar, then right-click a blank spot on the menu bar, and choose "Lock the toolbars".

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 nice find. You can add this to my post if you want.