# Grey Line on Windows Explorer, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I noticed yesterday when I hovered my mouse over a part of windows ezplorer, there was a small grey line, where the explorer toolbar normally goes. However over the line shows this cursor:

[image]

This is the line in the question, the images I found on another stack exchange question.

[image]

I know this my might be seem like a duplicate but I didnt find the answer on the other similar question.

Is this a default line on Windows 7? I set a system restore up and found system restore effects this bar. I did a restore to about 3 days ago, and the bar was still there, so its obviously been here before I noticed.

Another machine with oem hp windows 7 doesnt have this line. Can other software change how this line appears?

Just like to point out these images came from another superuser question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get rid of the file explorer grey bar line](http://superuser.com/questions/778412/get-rid-of-the-file-explorer-grey-bar-line), http://superuser.com/questions/355705/windows-explorer-line-above-command-bar?rq=1

Comment: That is windows 8, this is windows 7.

Comment: It's the same thing -- the line shows up unless you "Lock" the toolbar.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I have been able to lock it, but im wondering where it originated.  From software, or is it default?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Is the toolbar Unlocked by default? Dunno, could be (I don't think so though). It could be pretty easy to accidentally right-click and toggle it though.

Comment: I was just clicking about,  and I noticed I clicked the line and the double ended arrow came up. I cant recall ever using the menu/toolbar on explorer in the past.

Comment: Infact, would there be a registry associated with this?

Comment: "Lock the Internet Explorer Toolbars (All Windows)" - http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1194/

Comment: Is that not for Internet explorer?

Comment: Same thing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact  default on my installation

```
HKCU/software/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Toolbar
```

I exported it as a text file, and the key

```
Name: Locked Type: REG_DWORD  Data 0x00000000 (0)
```

Was last writtren/modified at the date of installation. If I lock the toolbar, it changes to

```
0x00000000 (1)
```

Thanks everyone!